# Unit test stuck in instantiating tests mode

Tags: unit-testing, anaconda, pytest, python-unittest, dataspell

After installing dataspell and anaconda, I tried  to perform a testing of my classes. However, the testing is taking forever.

**A simple function**

```py
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

**Test**

```py
import unittest
from calculator import add


class TestCalculator(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_add(self):
        x = 2
        y = 3

        actual_result = 5
        expected_result = add(x, y)

        self.assertEqual(actual_result, expected_result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

It's working on my other computer. Is there settings to change or something else to install?

Comment: Please, include code in your question as a code block instead of an image.

Comment: @tmt, I have made the changes. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Can you perhaps share a profile dump?

```
import cProfile

profile = cProfile.Profile()
profile.enable()

try:
    import unittest

    from calculator import add


    class TestCalculator(unittest.TestCase):

        def test_add(self):
            x = 2
            y = 3

            actual_result = 5
            expected_result = add(x, y)

            self.assertEqual(actual_result, expected_result)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main()

finally:
    profile.dump_stats('test.profile')
```